# Does Python PIL resize maintain the aspect ratio?

Tags: python, resize, python-imaging-library

Does PIL resize to the exact dimensions I give it no matter what? Or will it try to keep the aspect ratio if I give it something like the `Image.ANTIALIAS` argument?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question because it was very unclear.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[How do I resize an image using PIL and maintain its aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio)

Image.resize from PIL will do exactly as told. No behind scenes aspect ratio stuff.

Comment: the linked answer uses - im.thumbnail , is this suggested in general? Or just when working with thumbnails

Answer (score 77):

Yes it will keep aspect ratio using **thumbnail** method:

```
image = Image.open(source_path)
image.thumbnail((500,500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save(dest_path, "JPEG")
```

Comment: ANTIALIAS method name update:
As of 2.7.0, all resize methods are ANTIALIAS & the real (new) name for the specific ANTIALIAS filter is LANCZOS. (Tho antialias is currently left for backwards compatibility)

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/releasenotes/2.7.0.html#antialias-renamed-to-lanczos

Comment: Note thought that the thumbnail method isn't equivalent in other regards - it won't blow up images to larger than they were, and it acts on the image object and doesn't return anything.

Comment: Also note, this function modifies the `Image` object in place. If you need to use the full resolution image as well, apply this method to a `copy()` of the original image, per the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#Image.thumbnail).

Comment: I am trying to resize 500x500 image to 1280x720. It does nothing `image.thumbnail((1280,720), Image.LANCZOS)`

Answer (score 22):

Recent Pillow version (since 8.3) have the following method to have an image resized to fit in given box with keeping aspect ratio.

```
image = ImageOps.contain(image, (2048,2048))
```

Comment: Depending on the intention, `ImageOps.fit(image, size)` could also be helpful.

Comment: @talljosh that's what I was looking for, pls post this as an answer!

Comment: What's the different this `contain` and the `thumbnail`?

Comment: I think contain allow to expand a smaller image

Comment: what does pil use to pad/fill?

Answer (score 9):

No, it does not. But you can do something like the following:

```
im = PIL.Image.open("email.jpg"))
width, height = im.size
im = im.resize((width//2, height//2))
```

Here the height and width are divided by the same number, keeping the same aspect ratio.

Comment: you need to assign the im back. im.resize is not modifying the original image. `im = im.resize((width//2, height//2))`

Answer (score 8):

Okay, so this requires a couple of lines of code to get what you want.

First you find the ratio, then you fix a dimension of the image that you want (height or width). In my case, I wanted height as 100px and let the width adjust accordingly, and finally use that ratio to find new height or new width.

So first find the dimensions:

```
width, height = logo_img.size
ratio = width / height
```

Then, fix one of the dimension:

```
new_height = 100
```

Then find new width for that height:

```
new_width = int(ratio * new_height)
            
logo_img = logo_img.resize((new_width, new_height))
```

Comment: I get an error when I try your solution. I get "_tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size =20x20 at 0x7FB6A9494EF0>" doesn't exist. Any idea?

Comment: @Robin can you post more information about it? Like how are you loading the image, is the extension or path right?

Comment: @ Shreyas. Thank you. I am not trying to save the file. I want it to load on a canevas. The canevas takes a portion of the monitor, so I cannot have the image pass the border of the frame. Your solution works when I save the file, but not if I want to use the resized file in a canevas. Any idea if it is possible to redirect the resized image to a canevas with our code?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. the thumbnail() method is what is needed here... One thing that hasn't been mentioned in this or other posts on the topic is that 'size' must be either a list or tuple. So, to resize to a maximum dimension of 500 pixels, you would call:
    image.thumbnail((500,500), Image.ANTIALIAS)

See also this post on the subject:
[How do I resize an image using PIL and maintain its aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your demand, if you want you can set a fixed height and width or if you want you can resize it with **aspect-ratio.**

For the aspect-ratio-wise resize you can try with the below codes :

**To make the new image half the width and half the height of the original image:**

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image.jpg")
resized_im = im.resize((round(im.size[0]*0.5), round(im.size[1]*0.5)))
        
#Save the cropped image
resized_im.save('resizedimage.jpg')
```

**To resize with fixed width and ratio wise dynamic height :**

```
from PIL import Image
new_width = 300
im = Image.open("img/7.jpeg")
concat = int(new_width/float(im.size[0]))
size = int((float(im.size[1])*float(concat)))
resized_im = im.resize((new_width,size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
#Save the cropped image
resized_im.save('resizedimage.jpg')
```

Comment: Can you do this based on a new_height instead of a new_width?

Answer (score 5):

Recent versions of Pillow have some useful methods in `PIL.ImageOps`.

Depending on exactly what you're trying to achieve, you may be looking for one of these:

- `ImageOps.fit(image, size [, …])` [(docs)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.fit) – resizes your image, maintaining its aspect ratio, and crops it to fit the given size
- `ImageOps.contain(image, size [, …])` [(docs)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.contain) – resizes your image, maintaining its aspect ratio, so that it fits within the given size

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Isn't `ImageOps.fit` the same as `Image.thumbnail`?

Comment: @Crashalot, `Image.thumbnail` is similar to `ImageOps.contain`. One main difference is that `Image.thumbnail` edits the image in-place whereas `ImageOps.contain` creates a new image. Also, the docs of `Image.thumbnail` says that the resulting thumbnail will be 'no larger than the given size'. I don't know if it's ever actually smaller than specified in practice though.

Answer (score 1):

One complete example:

```py
import PIL.Image


class ImageUtils(object):
    @classmethod
    def resize_image(cls, image: PIL.Image.Image, width=None, height=None) -> PIL.Image.Image:
        if height is None and width is not None:
            height = image.height * width // image.width
        elif width is None and height is not None:
            width = image.width * height // image.height
        elif height is None and width is None:
            raise RuntimeError("At lease one of width and height must be present")
        return image.resize((width, height))


def main():
    ImageUtils.resize_image(PIL.Image.open("old.png"), width=100).save("new.png")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -2):

I think following is the easiest way to do:

```
Img1 = img.resize((img.size),PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
```