# How do I resize images in python for machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I used a dataset of images for machine learning training. Each image had a width of 64px and a height of 64px as well. Now, I want to test my machine learning model using images from google. The problem is that google images are larger than training images, and I want to resize them so that their height and width are 64px (just like the images in the training set). Is there any way to do this in python? I did find some methods, but all of them maintain aspect ratio. So, I am unable to achieve 64 by 64 size.

Comment: What library do you plan on using for Machine Learning? Pytorch has a very nice function: `torchvision.transforms.CenterCrop()` which should work well.

Comment: I am making a logistic regression model from scratch.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for here. Do you need to resize the whole image to given size, or you want to used a cropped section.?

Comment: resize the whole image to a given size.

Comment: It seems that by default PIL doesn't maintain the aspect ratio, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Yes. I found the function.

Comment: from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('./dataset/image.jpeg')
image= image.resize((64,64))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python PIL resize maintain the aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232742/does-python-pil-resize-maintain-the-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983263/how-to-crop-an-image-using-pil

Answer (score 1):

I found the function in PIL that resizes the image and does not maintain the aspect ratio.

```py
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('./dataset/image.jpeg')
image= image.resize((64,64))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python-resize-image.

Install package:

```
pip install python-resize-image
```

Example:

```
from PIL import Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage

#open image file
with open('image.jpg', 'r+b') as fd_img:
    # create a PIL Image from file
    img = Image.open(fd_img)
    # resize image (contain)
    img = resizeimage.resize_contain(img, [64, 64])
    # covert to RBA incase it's RGBA
    img = img.convert("RGB")
    # save image
    img.save('resized-image.jpg', img.format)
```