# How to resize an uneven image (different width, height) to a fixed size image?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a dataset containing images with variable widths and heights. I want to resize them to a fixed size, e.g., 128 x 128 for my model. I can resize using PIL like

```
Image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

OR

```
Image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

The problem is that when the image width or height is smaller than 128px, these approaches dont resize the image to the desired size as they need to maintain the aspect ratio. I observed the same behavior with `ImageOps.contain()`.

Is there a better way to resize the images to a fixed dimension while maintaining the aspect ratio using python or pytorch (transforms.Resize() in this case squashes the output)?

Comment: I think this is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232742/does-python-pil-resize-maintain-the-aspect-ratio, using the thumbnail method.

Comment: normally, do a padding before resizing should be nice

Comment: @Beatdown Thumbnail has the same behavior. For example, if the image size is 185x57, after the operation it gives me 128x39.

Comment: hmm okay, did you try 'contain' e.g. image = ImageOps.contain(image, (2048,2048))?

Comment: @Beatdown Nope, I haven't tried it.

Comment: Give it a go, it's on the same page I linked earlier.

Comment: @Beatdown I just tried 'contain' it gives me 128x39 (same behavior).

Comment: @dtlam26 for the padding way I am thinking about the boundary pixels? they may affect the model training.

Comment: actually not, jitter image does not affect the model training much as you only pad  the image to square by extending width/height. A lot of new model training have applied this way though. 0 padding

Comment: @dtlam26 So should I pad it to some large size (greater than 128 in my case)? and then crop the 128x128 from the center?

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan you can pad it to a square image (185x57) to both x axis (185x185) and resize that square image to 128x128