ImageSequenceClip from moviepy library gives me Exception: ImageSequenceClip requires all images to be the same size
this is my function
def create_image_sequence(images, fps=None, aspectRatio=None, resolution=None):
    '''
    Takes request.FILE images and makes video sequence it finnaly transfers to gif
    
    DONT FORGET TO DELETE GIF
    '''
    
    #STORING IMAGES INTO TMP FOLDER
    imagesTMPpaths = []
    
    for key, value in images.items():
        ext = photo_extension(value)
        
        tmp_image = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=ext)
        tmp_image.write(io.BytesIO(value.read()).read())
        tmp_image.close()
        
        imagesTMPpaths.append(tmp_image.name)
        print(f'{key}: {value}')
    

    #GETTING SMALLEST WIDTH --------
    
    images_sizes = []
    
    for image_tmp_path in imagesTMPpaths:
        
        with Image.open(image_tmp_path) as img:
            
            width, height = img.size #returns duplets
            images_sizes.append([width*height, width, height])
        
    images_sizes.sort() #it automaticly sorts by its first value
    print('xxxxxxx\nSize resizing to: ', images_sizes[0], '\nxxxxxxx')
    
    #GETTING SMALLEST WIDTH end --------
    
    
    #RESIZE IMAGES TO SMALLEST ONE --------
    print('\nresizing proces\n-------')
    for image_tmp_path in imagesTMPpaths:
        #https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271003 (resize with black fillers/padding)
        
        with Image.open(image_tmp_path) as img:
            print('\noriginal size: ', img.size)

            imgModified = ImageOps.pad(Image.open(image_tmp_path), (images_sizes[0][1], images_sizes[0][2]), color='black')
            
            imgModified.save(image_tmp_path)
            print('modified size: ', imgModified.size)
            print('PASSED: ', imgModified.size == (images_sizes[0][1], images_sizes[0][2]), '\n')
        
        
    # Verify all images have been resized correctly
    for image_tmp_path in imagesTMPpaths:
        with Image.open(image_tmp_path) as img:
            img = Image.open(image_tmp_path)
            print('size: ', img.size)
            print('PASSED: ', img.size == (images_sizes[0][1], images_sizes[0][2]), '\n')
        
    
    print(imagesTMPpaths)
    print(type(fps))
    print(f'fps: --{fps}--')
    print(fps not in [None,''])
    
    
        
    # Creating image sequence clip
    if fps in [0, None, '']:
        fps = len(imagesTMPpaths)
    else:
        fps = int(fps)
    
    imageSequence = ImageSequenceClip(imagesTMPpaths, fps=fps)
    
    
        
    if resolution  not in [None,'no change']:
        width, height = map(int, resolution.split('x')) #split will split around X and map makes two outputs int
        print('Resolution allowed:', resolution)
        print(width, height)
        imageSequence = imageSequence.resize(newsize=(width, height))
        print("Resolution updated. New size:", imageSequence.size)
    
    # Adjust aspect ratio if specified
    if aspectRatio not in [None,'no change']:
        print('Aspect ratio allowed:', aspectRatio)
        x, y = map(int, aspectRatio.split(':'))
        
        imageSequence = imageSequence.resize(newsize=(imageSequence.size[0], int(imageSequence.size[0] * y / x)))
        print("Aspect ratio updated. New size:", imageSequence.size)
    
    
    #final GIF
    tmp_gif = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.gif')
    
    
    imageSequence.write_gif(tmp_gif.name, program = 'ffmpeg')#WRITING INTO --> tmp_gif,  when using same tmp_gif path!
    imageSequence.close()
    
    tmp_gif.close()
    
    for image_tmp_path in imagesTMPpaths:
        os.remove(image_tmp_path)
    
    return tmp_gif.name

Everything works fine until it hits imageSequence = ImageSequenceClip(imagesTMPpaths, fps=fps)
even after i validate in console that images have same width and length it still makes the exception.
This is output from console:
####-web-1  | 0: xddd.png
####-web-1  | 1: Candlera-7_c582e094-1714-43df-bc18-a56e8277bd91.webp
####-web-1  | xxxxxxx
####-web-1  | Size resizing to:  (111, 194) 
####-web-1  | xxxxxxx
####-web-1  | 
####-web-1  | original size:  (111, 194)
####-web-1  | modified size:  (111, 194)
####-web-1  | PASSED:  True
####-web-1  |
####-web-1  |
####-web-1  | original size:  (700, 700)
####-web-1  | modified size:  (111, 194)
####-web-1  | PASSED:  True
####-web-1  |
####-web-1  | size:  (111, 194)
####-web-1  | PASSED:  True
####-web-1  |
####-web-1  | size:  (111, 194)
####-web-1  | PASSED:  True

then it hits the exception: ImageSequenceClip requires all images to be the same size
As you see in code i tried resizing images to smallest image size but with same ratio from original image so i used this this: imgModified = ImageOps.pad(Image.open(image_tmp_path), (images_sizes[0][1], images_sizes[0][2]), color='black')
and after that i validated twice in console if the sizes are correct and output from console is showing it is same.
I tried to wipe entire tmp folder in docker but it didnt help i tried rebuild entire container and it didnt help.

Okay i think this code i posted was stupid, why generate video? wasting precious resources like this, my silly ass.
I will just use pillow library that i already have, it will be much more lighter on hardware.
I will use this tutorial: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-gif/


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Okay i solve it here is my function (please read comments so you can udnderstand it):

def create_image_sequence(images, fps=None, aspectRatio=None, resolution=None):
    '''
    Takes request.FILE images and makes video sequence it finnaly transfers to gif
    
    images = request.FILE
    fps= number input (can be a string)
    aspectRatio = must be in this string format --> 1:5 for example
    resolution= must be in this string format --> 1920:1080 for example
    '''
    
    #STORING IMAGES INTO TMP FOLDER
    imagesTMPpaths = []
    
    for key, value in images.items():
        ext = photo_extension(value)
        
        tmp_image = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=ext)
        tmp_image.write(io.BytesIO(value.read()).read())
        tmp_image.close()
        
        imagesTMPpaths.append(tmp_image.name)
        print(f'{key}: {value}')
    

    #GETTING SMALLEST WIDTH --------
    #why? because if you rezise images its better to resize it to smallest so you dont loose quality at smallest images
    images_sizes = []
    
    for image_tmp_path in imagesTMPpaths:
        
        with Image.open(image_tmp_path) as img:
            
            width, height = img.size #returns duplets
            images_sizes.append([width*height, width, height])
        
    images_sizes.sort() #it automaticly sorts by its first value
    print('xxxxxxx\nSize resizing to: ', images_sizes[0], '\nxxxxxxx')
    
    
    
    
    #GETTING SMALLEST WIDTH end --------
    
    
    #RESIZE IMAGES TO SMALLEST ONE --------
    print('\nresizing proces\n-------')
    for image_tmp_path in imagesTMPpaths:
        #https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271003 (resize with black fillers/padding -->  ImageOps.pad() function)
        
        with Image.open(image_tmp_path) as img:
            print('\noriginal size: ', img.size)
            
            if resolution  not in [None,'no change']:
                InputWidth, InputHeight = map(int, resolution.split('x')) #split will split around X and map makes two outputs int
                
                if aspectRatio not in [None,'no change']:
                    print('Aspect ratio allowed:', aspectRatio)
                    x, y = map(int, aspectRatio.split(':'))
                    
                    imgModified = ImageOps.pad(Image.open(image_tmp_path), (InputWidth, (InputWidth * x/y) ), color='black')
                    print("Aspect ratio updated. New size:", imgModified.size)
                else:
                    imgModified = ImageOps.pad(Image.open(image_tmp_path), (InputWidth, InputHeight), color='black')
                
                
            else:
                if aspectRatio not in [None,'no change']:
                    print('Aspect ratio allowed:', aspectRatio)
                    x, y = map(int, aspectRatio.split(':'))
                    
                    imgModified = ImageOps.pad(Image.open(image_tmp_path), (images_sizes[0][1], (images_sizes[0][2] * x/y) ), color='black')
                    print("Aspect ratio updated. New size:", imgModified.size)
                else:
                    imgModified = ImageOps.pad(Image.open(image_tmp_path), (images_sizes[0][1], images_sizes[0][2]), color='black')
            
            imgModified.save(image_tmp_path)
            print('size: ', imgModified.size)
            
    #GIF TEMP SAVEING LOCATION
    tmp_gif = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.gif')
    
    print('first image: ',imagesTMPpaths[0])
    
    gif = Image.open(imagesTMPpaths[0])
    
    
    if fps not in [0, None, '']:
        gif.save(tmp_gif.name, save_all=True, append_images=[Image.open(img) for img in imagesTMPpaths[1:]], duration=1000/int(fps), loop=0)
        
    else:
        gif.save(tmp_gif.name, save_all=True, append_images=[Image.open(img) for img in imagesTMPpaths[1:]], duration=1000, loop=0)
    
    
    tmp_gif.close()
    
    #deleting old images
    for image_tmp_path in imagesTMPpaths:
        os.remove(image_tmp_path)
    
    print('RETURNING GIF', tmp_gif.name)
    return tmp_gif.name


