# Image Height and Width in Windows and Python OpenCV2

Tags: python, opencv

[image: Bill Image]

The attached image is in Landscape mode. In windows, the image property is  `width =4032` and `height=3024`. But when I read using `cv2.imread` and get the Shape of it, it's showing height as 4032 and Width as 3024. It shows the same height and width even if I turn it into Portrait mode. Am I missing something?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer may be embedded in the EXIF header, which that version of the image appears to not have. If you took the picture using an iPhone, you might have run afoul of inconsistent handling of orientation. Googling for "iphone exif orientation" turns up lots of frustration.

See the answers to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872331/rotating-an-image-with-orientation-specified-in-exif-using-python-without-pil-in) for some tips on what you might do.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! That was very helpful.