# How to load an image file into a numpy array with Exif orientation support for multiple images at once in Python?

Tags: python, face-recognition

Just like the title says I m trying to Load an image file into a numpy array with Exif orientation support. I m doing this to Prevents upside-down and sideways images for face_recognition as it does not work on pictures taking by Iphones. To fix that I m using this script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import image_to_numpy

img = image_to_numpy.load_image_file("my_file.jpg")

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

This works for one image but I want to create a loop to do this with multiple images in a folder and save it in a different folder. Any idea on how to do that ?

Are you talking about something like this. I m pretty sure I m missing something in this below:

````
import glob
import os
for i in range(10)
  filepath = glob.glob(os.path.join('path/images/', *.jpg))
  try:
      image=Image.open(filepath)

      for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys():
          if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation]=='Orientation':
              break

      exif=dict(image._getexif().items())

      if exif[orientation] == 3:
          image=image.rotate(180, expand=True)
      elif exif[orientation] == 6:
          image=image.rotate(270, expand=True)
      elif exif[orientation] == 8:
          image=image.rotate(90, expand=True)

    image.save(filepath)
    image.close()
  except (AttributeError, KeyError, IndexError):
    # cases: image don't have getexif
    pass ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26928142/12076702.

The only changes you would need to make is to change `filepath` in `image=Image.open(filepath)` to the original image file path and this filepath, `image.save(filepath)` to the file path you want to save the image to.

You can use glob.glob() to get all the image file paths of a format of your choice in the specified directory by doing something like:

```
import glob
import os

filepaths = glob.glob(os.path.join('path', 'to', 'my', 'directory', '*.jpg'))
```

Then just do a for loop, opening the images, modifying them and finally saving them in the directory of you choice. Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you talking about something like this : See above.

Comment: `glob.glob()` will return a list of all the file paths that meet the specified requirements. You need to loop through all those. Here's some code I wrote on pastebin that should do that: https://pastebin.com/xDbt1dzt