# Why are width and height of an image are inverted when loading using PIL versus OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am loading an [image](https://i2.wp.com/kernut.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/20170217_162840.jpg?resize=1360%2C765) using *PIL* and *OpenCV* packages. The height and width are reversed when loading the image using `PIL` versus when loading using `cv2`. Following is the code to print height and width of the image loaded using both the packages.

```py
file = 'conceptual_captions/VL-BERT/data/conceptual-captions/val_image/00002725.jpg'
# load image using PIL
import PIL.Image
pil = PIL.Image.open(file).convert('RGB')
w, h = pil.size
print("width: {}, height: {}".format(w, h))
```

Print output
`width: 1360, height: 765`

```py
# now using cv2
import cv2
im = cv2.imread(file)
print("height, width, channels: {}".format(im.shape))
```

print output `height, width, channels: (1360, 765, 3)`

I downloaded the image and checked the size of the image using info option on Mac. Info has `width = 765` and `height = 1360`, which is same as reported by `cv2` method. Why is `PIL` giving wrong image dimensions?

The problem occurs with very few images. The image I have linked is one such image. For rest of the images, the height and width reported by `PIL` and `cv2` are the same.

Comment: What result do you get when you call `width, height = cv.GetSize(im)`, which is the documented way of getting the width and height?

Comment: @FrankYellin I get an error when I run the command `width, height = cv.GetSize(im)`. Also, [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html) mentions to use `im.shape` under "Accessing Image Properties" section. Can you link to the documentation for using `GetSize()`.

Comment: Oh, great.  One document I saw mentions GetSize(), another doesn't.  Sorry about that.  
But definitely `pil.size` returns width, height while `im.shape` returns height, width.  That's not what you're seeing?  (You're not showing the results of the print statement, just your interpretations of the results.)

Comment: @FrankYellin I have updated the question with the exact print outputs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The image has some EXIF meta data including information about orientation (rotation). I suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13872331/11089932) Q&A and subsequent references there.

Nevertheless, the proposed solution there can be simplified nowadays, just use [`PIL.ImageOps.exif_transpose()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.exif_transpose):

> If an image has an EXIF Orientation tag, return a new image that is transposed accordingly. Otherwise, return a copy of the image.

Some code to test:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

# Read original image, show width and height
file = '...'
pil = Image.open(file).convert('RGB')
w, h = pil.size
print("width: {}, height: {}".format(w, h))

# Transpose with respect to EXIF data
pil = ImageOps.exif_transpose(pil)
w, h = pil.size
print("width: {}, height: {}".format(w, h))
```

The corresponding output:

```
width: 1360, height: 765
width: 765, height: 1360
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:     Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:       3.8.5
Pillow:       7.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: The suggested edit worked on `PIllow 7.2.0` and `Python 3.6.8`. It did not work on `Pillow 6.2.0` and `Python 3.7.4`. With the later configuration, I got error when `ImageOps.exif_transpose(pil)` got called. Before I accept the answer, I have a related question. `exif_transpose()` is converting the image to correct orientation, which `cv2.imread` was doing automatically. Is that correct?