# Why is Tensorflow tf.image.decode_jpeg() rotating some images 90 degrees?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

I have many images which rotate 90 degrees when I use Tensorflow tf.image.decode_jpeg() to read in images in my data pipeline. When I look at those image on my computer they look correctly oriented and when I read the image with cv2 they also looks correctly oriented. However, when I read them in with Tensorflow tf.image.decode_jpeg(), they end up rotated 90 degrees. Anybody know why or how I can fix this so they read in the correct orientation (it doesn't happen to all images but many)?

To show what I mean, here's what a sample image looks like on my computer or when I read it with open-cv.

[image]

However, when I read it with Tensorflow (tensorflow 2.4.0) in my pipeline, many images rotate 90 degrees and, for example, the same image ends up looking like this.

[image]

To read and see an image with cv2 I do

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

%matplotlib inline

plt.imshow(cv2.imread(image_file_path)[:, :, ::-1]))
```

To read and see many rotated image with Tensorflow

```
def decode_images(dataset_file_paths):
    '''
    tf_read_converted_file_path = tf.io.read_file(dataset_file_paths) 
    return tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf_read_converted_file_path)

def check_processed_images(files_path_dataset, processing_function):
'''Plots images to see what the processing looks like when it is mapped in from a dataset. 
This can be used to, for example, look see how the augmentation of images look.

Arguments:
    files_path_dataset: TF TensorSliceDataset of filenames.
    processing_function: function which is used to map each element in the dataset.
    
Return:
    plot of images'''

augmentation_dataset = files_path_dataset.map(processing_function).shuffle(50).batch(16)

plt.figure(figsize=(13, 13))
for images, labels in augmentation_dataset.take(1):
    for i in range(16):
        ax = plt.subplot(4, 4, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy())
        
####################
####################
# Look at a sample of images
# Take a directory of jpg images and create a TensorFlow dataset of filepaths
dirPath = type_in_a_directory_here
fileNames = tf.io.gfile.glob(f'{dirPath}/**/*.jpg')
fileNames = tf.random.shuffle(fileNames)
filenamesDs = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(fileNames)

check_processed_images(filenamesDs, decode_images)
```

The code above will produce a grid of images so you can see. For example, all these images on my computer have the fishing lure so that they are horizontal but when I use TensorFlow to process my images many are rotated 90 degrees for some reason.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong that Tensorflow is rotating many of my images?

Comment: Camera orientation (potrait vs landscape) info in metadata could cause this. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63798032/2580077 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/39132878/2580077

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I found out the problem. All the images are positioned correctly when viewing them as thumbnails and when opening them with the program "Preview" on my Mac. However, when I look at the actual dimensions of the images under their properties, many of them are actually supposed to look rotated 90 degrees. I have no clue why this is happening but as far as this, the problem has been discovered.

Answer (score -2):

It's not rotating the image, it's pyplot that represents the images with the format `[W, H, D]` (Widht, Height, Depth), while TensorFlow and OpenCV use the format `[H,W,D]`.

If you want to visualize the image without rotation with pyplot, you should transpose it using `tf.transpose`