# Resize and move Images using lambda function from one s3 to another s3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, devops

> WHAT I WANT TO DO

- I have 3 buckets. I want to trigger a lambda function when an image
  uploaded to bucket1.
- The lambda function will resize that image
  (500x500) and save that resized image in bucket2.
- the main image on bucket1 will be backed up in bucket3.
- the main image on bucket1 will be deleted then.

> WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR

- wrote a lambda function that will move images across the bucket.
- Made S3 trigger to the lambda function

> WHERE IS MY PROBLEM

- I am using PIL to resize the image. But PIL module is not in python STL. So I zipped my code
  with site packages and able to run. But the error says file not found.
  an example of a file key image/myimage.jpg
- Though I followed tutorials but if I try to use lambda layers instead of zipping everytime it seems not to find the PIL module.

> CODE

```
import boto3
import os
import sys
import uuid
from PIL import Image
import PIL.Image

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def resize_image(image_path, resized_path):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        image.thumbnail((500, 500))
        image.save(resized_path)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #
    # giving a key error here event['Records']
    #
    for record in event['Records']: 
        bucket = 'mahabubelahibucket1'
        key = record['s3']['object']['key'] 
        download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
        upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(key)

        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        resize_image(download_path, upload_path)
        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, 'mahabubelahibucket2', key)
```

Comment: Did you forget to add the created layer in layers section of your lambda?

Comment: Hi @omuthu 
No I did not. First I created a lambda layer and then add that layer by ARN in function.

Comment: Sounds a lot like: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html). The tutorial includes steps for creating a zip with all required libraries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### This is my solution to the problem !

```
import boto3
import os
from PIL import Image
import pathlib
from io import BytesIO

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def delete_this_bucket(name):
    bucket = s3.Bucket(name)
    for key in bucket.objects.all():
        try:
            key.delete()
            bucket.delete()
        except Exception as e:
            print("SOMETHING IS BROKEN !!")

def create_this_bucket(name, location):
    try:
        s3.create_bucket(
            Bucket=name,
            CreateBucketConfiguration={
                'LocationConstraint': location
            }
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def upload_test_images(name):
    for each in os.listdir('./testimage'):
        try:
            file = os.path.abspath(each)
            s3.Bucket(name).upload_file(file, each)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

def copy_to_other_bucket(src, des, key):
    try:
        copy_source = {
            'Bucket': src,
            'Key': key
        }
        bucket = s3.Bucket(des)
        bucket.copy(copy_source, key)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def resize_image(src_bucket, des_bucket):
    size = 500, 500
    bucket = s3.Bucket(src_bucket)
    in_mem_file = BytesIO()
    client = boto3.client('s3')

    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        file_byte_string = client.get_object(Bucket=src_bucket, Key=obj.key)['Body'].read()
        im = Image.open(BytesIO(file_byte_string))

        im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        # ISSUE : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228530/pil-thumbnail-is-rotating-my-image
        im.save(in_mem_file, format=im.format)
        in_mem_file.seek(0)

        response = client.put_object(
            Body=in_mem_file,
            Bucket=des_bucket,
            Key='resized_' + obj.key
        )

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = s3.Bucket('myimagebucket0099')

    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        copy_to_other_bucket(bucket, 'backupimagebucket0099', obj.key)

    resize_image(bucket.name, 'resizedimagebucket0099')


    print(bucket)
```