# To find size of int, float, double and char of my System in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and i am trying to find size of int, float, double and char of my System.
 Do we have any syntax to find them?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860588/maximum-value-for-long-integer) question.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about C/C++/Java/C#/... types, not about Python types. Please clarify.

Comment: There is no such thing as `double` or `char` in Python.

Comment: There is definitely types in python. You can check the type of a variable using the type(varname) command.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at `sys.getsizeof`.  But it is more complicated than you may think.

Comment: Note the difference between `sys.getsizeof(int)` and `sys.getsizeof(int())`

Answer (score 3):

`int` technically has a finite size, but if the result of a computation goes past that size, Python will automatically use an arbitrary-precision `long` instead. Those are only limited by available memory.

`float` is an IEEE 64-bit binary floating-point number. Many other languages would call that a double.

`double` and `char` don't exist in Python. Python only has one built-in floating-point data type, which is `float`. Single-character strings are used to represent characters.

Answer (score 1):

One can use [ctypes.sizeof](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.sizeof) on ctypes' c_int, c_float, c_double, and c_char types respectively to find the size of the type in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

These sizes are system independent and represent the number of bytes and precision.  A little bit of [googling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) brings up a chart of the primitive data types and their data footprint.

Things get more complicated when concerning data structures and objects.