# create a matrix in python with floating point indices

Tags: python, data-structures

I need a data structure in python similar to a matrix with fast access to nearby cells
but with floating point indices.The Data size(number of points) is pretty large so I cannot scale the data to make it integral.

Note:
The data is 3-dimentional coordinates 
ex: -3.4561  5.5985  0.3249

This is one cell.Similarly there are other cells.
Each cell has an integral value inside it with range 0-100. 
I don't need full precision,two digits after decimal point are sufficient.

Comment: Floating point indices in general makes no sense. How does your data look like, and how do you need to query it?

Comment: it seems weird to have floats as indices. Can you show some code to clarify what you mean?

Comment: I remember python integers have no limited precision, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860588/maximum-value-for-long-integer

Comment: Sounds like you something like a kd-tree, not a matrix.

Comment: Is what you need, interpolation between nearby cells?

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Multiple your indices by 100, and round. End of story.

Comment: Not interpolation, what I need is ability to access any cell individually through the indices and get the value inside it.

Comment: I can't round of the indices. I wrote coordinates to make clear that I don't want to make changes to the indices.

Comment: Isn't this called a function of three parameters ?

Comment: multiply by 100 and rounding should be more than good enough, since you say yourself you don't need more than 2 decimals in precision. You could subclass and modify the getitem and setitem method to do this for you if you please.

Comment: Multiplying and rounding off solves the problem but I need to use the coordinates as they are.  If the coordinates are: 2.3645,3.6384,1.7643 then I should be able to access through 2.36,3,63,1.76. The other parts of the program require this.

Comment: why not store it in a data structure eg tuple  (x, y, z, val).   I assume you later want to plot or do some kind of visualization with it.   in that case you can write functions that gets the value "closest" to a given s dimensional point.   In essence your data to be "samples" within a space.   treat it like that.   Pandas might give you good tools to deal with it.

Comment: Can you write some pseudo code showing exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

"two digits after decimal point are sufficient"

Multiply the floats by 100 and truncate. Now they are integers and it works as expected.

If your data is sparse consider using a dictionary instead of a matrix with the coordinates(ints) as a tuple.