# Python: integer precision and type checking

Tags: python

I'm writing a python (2.7.6) script that pulls JSON data from a webserver and publishes it elsewhere. I only want to publish those JSON values that are numeric, e.g. no sub-objects or strings. It's very likely that the numeric values will exceed the size of `int` (in the C sense of size). My current code looks like this:

```
for metric, currentValue in json.items()
    if type(currentValue) is int:
        oldValue = previous.get(metric)
        if oldValue is None:
            oldValue = 0

        delta = currentValue - oldValue
        publish(metric, delta)
        previous[metric] = currentValue
```

My concern is the type check. If Python decides that `int` is no longer appropriate and uses `long` instead it means some metrics will not get published. And what to do if `long` gets exceeded?

What I really want is a way to check that `currentValue` is numeric.
There is `isdigit` but that doesn't work for negatives or floats.

Comment: [`isinstance(currentValue, (int, long))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)? `long` can't get exceeded (unless your RAM does - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9860588/3001761), it's arbitrary precision.

Comment: Note that `isdigit` only works for *strings*; if that's what you've got, you will need to convert them to numbers explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `isinstance` instead of `type`

Example -

```
isinstance(currentValue, (int, long))
```

If you want to consider float as well, then -

```
isinstance(currentValue, (int, long, float))
```

Comment: See the [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html) module for more inclusive types (`numbers.Integral`, for example, includes `int`, `long`, and `bool`).