# Dealing with uint64_t length conversion to Py_ssize_t

Tags: python, indexing, types, cython

I am reading a binary data format which contains a `length` field of type `unsigned long long` using cython.

After reading this value, I cast it to a `Py_ssize_t` variable to return to python space to be used in indexing.

Since `Py_ssize_t` is signed, it's maximum positive range must be lower than the maximum value `unsigned long long`.

Is there a general way of checking if the value I read can be stored in `Py_ssize_t`? Or put differently: Is there a way to obtain the maximum positive value of `Py_ssize_t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare to [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) which is the maximum value `Py_ssize_t` can take (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9860611/))