# TypeError when setting y-axis range in pyplot

Tags: matplotlib

I am getting a TypeError like this for the following code.

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import math

    plt.axis([1,5000,100,10**20])
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.savefig('test.png')
    plt.close()
```

When I set the maximum value for y-axis as 10^19, there is no error.
But from 10^20, I start getting the TypeError described above.

Could you help me understand this error and set the y-axis range from 1 to 10^20?

Comment: I found that the error doesn't occur if instead of `10**20` you write `1.e20`. Also I found that that the range of 64bit-integers is of order `10**18`: `float(2**63)` gives `9.223372036854776e+18`. I can't explain this way why you start to experience problems from `10**20` on, except one assumes that because of the log-scaled axes unsigned integers are used. Then the max range is of order `10**19` and larger numbers might cause problems. Then again the order of the commands does not speak for that argumentation.

Comment: Notice that the error comes from the NumPy function `np.isfinite`. `np.isfinite(10**19)` gives `True` while `np.isfinite(10**20)` gives that error. Even though Python can handle arbitrarly large integers, NumPy is written in C and works with standard data types like 64bit integers.

Comment: `type(10**10)` will get you  `<type 'long'>`, while `type(1e20)` returns `<type 'float'>`. And although [there's no limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860588/maximum-value-for-long-integer) on how large a long can be, somewhere inside the power calculation there must be some limitation. Try with floats as suggested by @Michael.