# How do I use Python to generate a random number that is greater than a specified one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, osx-yosemite, python-3.6

By this I mean I need Python to generate any random number under one condition, it must be greater than the user defined number (lets say "x"), in other words it would be like saying x>num>infinity.

I tried using the random module but can't seem to figure anything out, as I tried something like this

```
import random
import math
inf=math.inf
x=15
random.randint(x,inf)
```

But that doesn't work because infinity is registered as a floating point number and the randint function only works with integers. I also tried something like this

```
import random
import math
inf=math.inf
x=15
random.uniform(x,inf)
```

This should work because the uniform function works with floating points, but it just ends up returning infinity every time.

This would mean that I need someway to get this done without using infinity (or math.inf) within my range, I just need the range to have a minimum (x) and no maximum at all. Any suggestions?

*I'm running Python 3.6.0b4 on OS X Yosemite*

Comment: Do you actually want an integer? Then `random.randint(x, sys.maxsize)` would do it, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7604966/3001761

Comment: If you're okay with longs then you can make the number as big as your memory can fit.

Comment: An uniform distribution can only be defined on a bounded interval. So, trying to use it between some value and infinity makes no sense.

Comment: I think sys.maxsize should work fine, thanks!

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because the requirement does not make **mathematical** sense, per @ThierryLathuille 's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific maximum integer.  See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860588/maximum-value-for-long-integer)

Use `sys.maxsize` instead.

> sys.maxsize An integer giving the maximum value a variable of type Py_ssize_t can take. It’s usually 2^31 - 1 on a 32-bit platform and 2^63 - 1 on a 64-bit platform.

To *limit* the upper bound to some lesser value, one could simply define a maximum that is less than that implied by `sys.maxsize`.  For example, the 64-bit maximum signed integer `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` could be limited to `999,999,999,999,999L` for 15 decimal places.  You could just use that or any long integer less than that implied by `sys.maxsize`.

Comment: Is there any way to limit the output to a certain amount of digits?

Comment: @JadMoussa yes, of course see my edited answer above.  Thanks for accepting!