# Python - Using List Comprehension to duplicate an array and replace elements

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list:`distance = [0,6,6,maxsize]`

How can I use list comprehension to create a new list with every `maxsize` element replaced with a `-1` and with every `0` removed?

I want the result as this:

```
distance1 = [6,6,-1]
```

I have tried this so far but it's a syntax error:

```
distance1=[-1 if v == maxsize else v if v != 0 for v in distance]
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: maxsize is the largest positive integer supported In pythons regular integer type.

Comment: I think everybody is asking themselves "what is maxsize?"

Comment: I think your syntax error is that you're nesting ternaries without giving the second ternary an else statement.

Comment: maxsize is the largest positive integer supported In pythons regular integer type. I'm sorry I should have specified this in the original post.

Comment: If I do something like this and add another else statement: asdf=[-1 if v == maxsize else v if v != 0 else v for v in distance], it doesn't get rid of the zeroes. Any idea how I can add the second else statement and also get rid of the zeroes?

Comment: Check out this post for info on max int value - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860588/maximum-value-for-long-integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is maxsize a variable, the length of the array or a string?

```
distance1 = [-1 if v == maxsize else v for v in filter(lambda x: x, distance)]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified this. Maxsize is the largest integer supported by Pythons integer type. You can import it: from sys import maxsize