# Why do i keep getting " ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '5-1'

Tags: python-2.7, traceback, valueerror

I think the error means that it is receiving some other data type although it expects another kind but i may be wrong since i am a beginner at python.Anyone knows how this can be fixed?

```
#Program to calculate factorial of a long number

def multiply(multiplier,multiplicand):

    a = long(''.join(multiplier))
    b = long(''.join(multiplicand))
    a = a*b
    multiplier = list(str(a))
    b = b-1
    multiplicand = list(str(b))
    if(b == 1):
        return False,multiplier,multiplicand
    else:
        return True,multiplier,multiplicand


num = ""
f = True # A flag variable
while(f):                 #checks if the string consists of digits only
        num = raw_input("Enter number:")  
        f = False
        if num.isdigit() == False:
                print "oops,try again!"
                f = True
multiplier = list(num)
multiplicand = multiplier[:]
multiplicand.pop()
multiplicand.insert(len(multiplier),str(long(multiplier[-1])-1)) #mand now contains   multiplier -1 in list form 

f = True
while (f):
        f,multiplier,multiplicand = multiply(multiplier,multiplicand)
num = ''.join(multiplier)
print num  #print the ans as a string
```

The code runs fine as long as the value entered is below 50,but after 50 it shows the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    f,multiplier,multiplicand = multiply(multiplier,multiplicand)
File "test.py", line 5, in multiply
    b = long(''.join(multiplicand))
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '5-1'
```

What does '5-1' mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are treating multi-digit numbers as lists, and reimplementing substraction. You want `mand = mplier - 1`. Since `mplier` is a list of digits (there is no need for this, more information at the end of the answer) you are assuming that `mand` should be identical to `mplier` except the last digit, which should be the last digit of `mplier` minus 1.

This holds true for numbers which do not end in 0: `['5', '3']` would become `['5', '2']`, but `['5', '0']` would become `['5', '-1']`, not `['4', '9']`. When you try to reassemble your number in `b = long(''.join(mand))` you end up with `b = long('4-1')`, and `'4-1'` is not a number, so you get an exception.

[Python does not have a precision limit on integer numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860588/maximum-value-for-long-integer), so you don't need to treat long numbers differently.

I have rewritten your code in case it's useful:

```
#Program to calculate factorial of a long number

def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for r in xrange(0, n):
        result = result * (r+1)
    return result

num = 0

while(True):                 #checks if the string consists of digits only
        num = raw_input("Enter number:")
        if not num.isdigit():
                print "oops,try again!"
        else:
            num = int(num)
            break

print factorial(num)
```

Also, as a side note, the code is confusing and it took me a bit to understand what you were doing. You could probably benefit from [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to learn best practices (useful variable names, getting rid of useless variables, proper documentation of the code, newest techniques...).