# Why this z3 equation is failing?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I need to solve this code (the code in C)

```
if ( ((0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABLL * len_input_serial >> 64) >> 1)+ len_input_serial- 3 * ((0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABLL * len_input_serial >> 64) >> 1) != 14)
    return 0xFFFFFFFFLL;
```

that's my python script

```
from z3 import *
len_input_serial = BitVec("serial_len",64)
solve(LShR(LShR(0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABL * len_input_serial,64),1) + len_input_serial - 3 * LShR(LShR(0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABL * len_input_serial,64),1) == 14)
```

However this gives me `[serial_len = 14]`

I know the solution should be around `[42,38,40]`, so what's wrong here ?

Comment: is it intentional that your python code uses `A...ABL` instead of `A...ABLL`?

Comment: i guess it doesn't matter  .. i tried to set len_input_serial to 40 and run the code in python i got 14 which is the right number

Comment: What do you mean "solve?" Are you trying to find a value for `len_input_serial` so that the test of `if` statement would evaluate to true?

Comment: No i need values which evaluates false
which i know is 40,38,42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression:

```
(0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABLL * len_input_serial >> 64) >> 1
```

Is always equivalent to `0`. If you right shift a 64-bit quantity to the right by 64 bits, you get 0. (Note that you are using `LShr`, which treats its input as an unsigned quantity.)

Therefore the whole thing simplifies to solving `len_input_serial == 14`, which is the answer Z3 is producing.

Note that when you write a long integer in Python (i.e., 0x123L etc.), you get infinite precision. (See here: [Maximum value for long integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860588/maximum-value-for-long-integer)). In C, you get (most-likely) 64-bit integer. So, your Z3 code is actually correct; it's Python that's using a bigger precision here and thus causing the confusion.