# Confused about max_int in python3

Tags: python, integer

I don’t understand how my code can produce integers bigger than the local max_int! The fibonacci(100) below produces an integer greater than sys.maxsize.

```
    known={0:0,1:1}
    def fibonacci(n):
    if n in known:
        return known[n]
    res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    known[n]=res
    return res
    print(fibonacci(100))
```

**354224848179261915075**

```
    type(known[100])
```

**int**

```
    import sys
    print(sys.int_info)
```

**sys.int_info(bits_per_digit=30, sizeof_digit=4)**

```
    print(sys.maxsize)
```

**9223372036854775807**

Source: Think Python, version 2.0.17, p107, 2012 Allen Downey.

Comment: So why do you think that `sys.maxsize` and the `int` type should be connected?

Comment: You can read an interesting discussion about the maximum value a variable can hold in Python here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860588/maximum-value-for-long-integer
In short - numbers are converted to `long`s once they go over the `int` limit. From there they don't hold an explicitly defined limit.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed, Python3 does not have `maxint`.  And the documentation clearly states for `maxsize`.

> An integer giving the maximum value a variable of type Py_ssize_t can
> take. It’s usually 2**31 - 1 on a 32-bit platform and 2**63 - 1 on a
> 64-bit platform.

So this has nothing to do with the maximum integer size in Python

Comment: Wow! And thank you. So …
```print(fibonacci(500))```
**139423224561697880139724382870407283950070256587697307264108962948325571622863290691557658876222521294125**

This just amazes me.