# Node gm - resize image and preserve aspect ratio?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

Does Node gm have built-in support for resizing an image while preserving aspect ratio (ie., generating a thumbnail)?  Or should I get the image size, calculate the proper ratio, and then call resize?

This question is inspired by [PIL's similar functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio).

Comment: just use `gm().resize(maxSize)`. it automatically resizes so that the image's max dimension is `maxSize`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.  Do you want to add it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @JonathanOng where is `maxSize` defined?

Comment: @asus According to the latest node gm api docs, `resize` takes the width in pixels.  You can also call `gm().resize(width, height)`.  See https://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html.

Comment: ah your comment is from 2012..things have changed. I am passing both `width` and `height` as specified by the docs but thought I may have missed the `maxSize` arg that you 2 were discussing thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jonathan's comment is the solution:

```
gm().resize(maxSize)
```

This resizes the image to width `maxSize`.  See the [relevant documentation](https://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html).