# Python / Pillow: How to scale an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-scaling

Suppose I have an image which is 2322px x 4128px. How do I scale it so that both the width and height are both less than 1028px?

I won't be able to use [`Image.resize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) since that requires me to give both the new width and height. What I plan to do is (pseudo code below):

```
if (image.width or image.height) > 1028:
    if image.width > image.height:
        tn_image = image.scale(make width of image 1028)
        # since the height is less than the width and I am scaling the image
        # and making the width less than 1028px, the height will surely be
        # less than 1028px
    else: #image's height is greater than it's width
        tn_image = image.scale(make height of image 1028)
```

I am guessing I need to use `Image.thumbnail`, but according to [this example](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#create-thumbnails) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273946/4865723), both the width and the height are provided in order to create the thumbnail. Is there any function which takes either the new width or the new height (not both) and scales the entire image?

Comment: Where is a problem with providing both width and height to `Image.thumbnail`? You want to do exactly that with your custom code.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Noo need to reinvent the wheel, there is the [`Image.thumbnail`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail) method available for this:

```
maxsize = (1028, 1028)
image.thumbnail(maxsize, PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Ensures the resulting size is not bigger than the given bounds while maintains the aspect ratio.

Specifying `PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS` applies a high-quality downsampling filter for better resize result, you probably want that too.

Comment: oh, I misunderstood what thumbnail does. I thought image.thumbnail(1028, 1028) resizes the image to 1028 width and 1028 height... I didn't know image.thumbnail(1028, 1028) scales the image so that both the width and height are less than 1028

Comment: @user2719875 I would strongly suggest adding the `Image.ANTIALIAS` parameter.

Comment: If using Pillow >= 2.5.0, `Image.ANTIALIAS` is the [default](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/commit/22a370afc219af47907b2fe69e791854dd2d9c79) for `Image.thumbnail()`.

Comment: Notice that according to the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail) "Note that this function modifies the Image object in place. If you need to use the full resolution image as well, apply this method to a copy() of the original image."

Answer (score 22):

Use Image.resize, but calculate both width and height.

```
if image.width > 1028 or image.height > 1028:
    if image.height > image.width:
        factor = 1028 / image.height
    else:
        factor = 1028 / image.width
    tn_image = image.resize((int(image.width * factor), int(image.height * factor)))
```