# Resample the Image Pixels in Python

Tags: python, image, pixel, resampling

I have an image of 300*300 pixels size and want to convert it into 1500*1500 pixels size using python. I need this because i have to georeferenced this image with 1500*1500 pixel raster image. Any python library function or basic fundamental how to do this are welcome.

Comment: What about [scipy.misc.imresize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html)?

Comment: Can [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio) help you?

Answer (score 3):

You should try using Pillow (fork of PIL = Python Image Library)

Simple like this:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("my_image.png")
img.resize((1500, 1500, ))
img.save("new_image.png")
```