# Can't change the size of the drawing canvas while using graph-tool 2.2.44

Tags: python, graph-visualization, graph-tool

I'm trying to use Graph-Tool 2.2.44 on a Mac to visualize some networks with its function graph_tool.draw.graph_draw() in the following way:

```
    gt.graph_draw(g, pos=pos, output_size=(1200, 1200))
```

The visualization window will show up. However, no matter how I change the parameter output_size, the actual size of the drawing canvas just remains the same(seems the default size 600*600), which really bothers me when visualizing some large graphs.

Does anyone know something about this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio Perhaps it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed in git.

In the meantime, you should be able to achieve the same by passing `geometry=(1200, 1200)`, or by resizing the window manually with the mouse.