# How do I place an image (.png) within a `LabelFrame`, and resize it, in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to place a .png image within a `LabelFrame` in a `Tkinter` window. I imported `PIL` so .png image types should be supported (right?). I can't seem to get the image to show up.

Here is my revised code:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

make_frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Sample Image", width=150, height=150)
make_frame.pack()


stim = "image.png"
width = 100
height = 100
stim1 = stim.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.open(stim1))
in_frame = Label(make_frame, image = img)
in_frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

With this code, I got an AttributeError that reads: "'str' has no attribute 'resize'"

Comment: use an absolute path for the image file?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. All I did was change `Tkinter` to `tkinter` (I only have PIL installed for Python 3) and `image.png` to the name of a PNG file in the working directory, and it worked fine.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it either. It worked perfectly in Python 2.7.9. Could you edit your post and add the exact error text?

Comment: There's a file in my repository named "image.png," so I don't think I need to use an absolute path. @TigerhawkT3 did you change the name from the initial import?

Comment: Okay, I got it to work, but my image is too big. Can I shrink it to the size of my `LabelFrame`?

Comment: `LabelFrame`, like other container widgets, will expand to the size of its contents. If you want, you can comment out the image code to find the default size of a `LabelFrame`, then resize the image to that size with PIL's `resize()` method.

Comment: Since I specified the size of my `LabelFrame` can I just fit the image to that size? What arguments does `resize()` take?

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks, friends

Comment: @Mickey You should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I spoke too soon! I got an error: "'str' object has no attribute 'resize'"

Comment: I edited the original question with the code I've got now and the error that comes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Mickey,

You have to call the `.resize` method on the `PIL.Image` object and not the filename, which is a string. Also, you may prefer to use `PIL.Image.thumbnail` instead of `PIL.Image.resize`, for reasons described clearly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio). Your code was close, but this might be what you need:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

make_frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Sample Image", width=100, height=100)
make_frame.pack()

stim_filename = "image.png"

# create the PIL image object:
PIL_image = Image.open(stim_filename)

width = 100
height = 100

# You may prefer to use Image.thumbnail instead
# Set use_resize to False to use Image.thumbnail
use_resize = True

if use_resize:
    # Image.resize returns a new PIL.Image of the specified size
    PIL_image_small = PIL_image.resize((width,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
else:
    # Image.thumbnail converts the image to a thumbnail, in place
    PIL_image_small = PIL_image
    PIL_image_small.thumbnail((width,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

# now create the ImageTk PhotoImage:
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL_image_small)
in_frame = Label(make_frame, image = img)
in_frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```