# How to resize with rescaling?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an image that I want to resize - but can tolerate rescaling. The suggestions I have found all maintain the [aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio) -

```
import os, sys
import Image

size = 128, 128

for infile in sys.argv[1:]:
    outfile = os.path.splitext(infile)[0] + ".thumbnail"
    if infile != outfile:
        try:
            im = Image.open(infile)
            im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            im.save(outfile, "JPEG")
        except IOError:
            print "cannot create thumbnail for '%s'" % infile
```

I've tried thumbnail and resize - but they are maintain aspect. How can I resize/rescale without maintaining aspect?

Answer (score 0):

- `.thumbnail` preserves the aspect ratio and modifies the image inplace.
- `.resize` does not preserve aspect ratio, and returns a new image.

---

```
im = Image.open(infile)
im = im.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Comment: Strange - my resize code wasnt doing this - it was returning a scaled image