# Image thumbnail with at least a certain size in PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to resize an image maintaining its aspect ratio such that its smallest size is `500px`.

Using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273962/4480180) answer works, but it resize the image based on largest size.

So if we have a `2000x1000` image and we set `size= 500,500` the resulting image will be `500x250`, while I desire `1000x500`. How can I do it?

Obviously these are random numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Use `max` instead of `min`. Observe the different results:

```
>>> maxwidth = 500
>>> maxheight = 500
>>> width = 2000
>>> height = 1000
>>> i = min(maxwidth/width, maxheight/height)
>>> a = max(maxwidth/width, maxheight/height)
>>> width*i, height*i
(500.0, 250.0)
>>> width*a, height*a
(1000.0, 500.0)
```

You can use these values to determine what size you should be sending to `img.thumbnail`:

```
x,y = 500, 500
# compute i and a above
m.thumbnail((x*a/i, y*a/i), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```