# Scale images in directory to fit a letterbox

Tags: python, linux, image

I have a directory of images that I need to scale them down. I need to maintain the aspect ratio, and at the same time have a predefined width and height so basically I need to fit it in a letter box.

For example, I have this image: 
[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a87st.jpg)

Which I scaled down to this: 
[Scaled image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4TJP.jpg)

Is there any application that can do that in Linux? I found online apps but they do a single image at a time which does not scale with the number of images that I have.

I can do that in Python as well by using:

```
scipy.misc.imresize(img, [width, height])
```

but this loses the ratio as well.

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio

Comment: I would use  ImageMagick (i.e., convert -resize WIDTHxHEIGHT), not sure if it can process bunch of images using a single command, however, I believe the overhead of a bash loop and launch of the new process for each conversion would be negligible when compared to the conversion itself (if you don't have really tiny images).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="/path/*.jpg"
for f in $FILES
do
  convert $f -resize 200x200 -background white -extent 200x200 +repage $f
  # rm "$f"
done
```

This will overwrite the old image into the new images with the specified size.

Comment: Note that you might want to add a `-gravity center` as well to center the original image data on the background.