# Why does Image.resize crop the image

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use `Image.resize` from `PIL` to resize an image. However, when it resizes the image it crops off about 5% from the left side of the image. Any idea how to keep it from cropping the image? Here's my code:

```
imgOut = Image.open('sample-out.jpg')
new_img = imgOut.resize((640,384), Image.ANTIALIAS)
new_img.save("small-out.jpg", "JPEG", optimize=True)
```

Comment: Not enough information. Even so: does `Image.resize` maintain the original aspect ratio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resize an image using PIL and maintain its aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio)

Comment: I also suspect that the new size may have another ration than the original. Also: do you use the "real" PIL or Pillow? PIL wasn't updated in 8 years, I suggest using Pillow https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

Comment: Looks like the full Pillow did the trick. Thanks for the help!