# resizing all images in a folder using PIL

Tags: python, resize, python-imaging-library

i'm able to resize each image one at a time,but how can I resize all images in one folder in a similar way? Please help me.

```
from PIL import Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage
    with open('test-image.jpeg', 'r+b') as f:
        with Image.open(f) as image:
            cover = resizeimage.resize_cover(image, [200, 100])
            cover.save('test-image-cover.jpeg', image.format)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Looks like you've got some code that should do something - can you share an example of the output/error message that you are getting? That would help people to understand your problem. Also, it looks like you are using the `resizeimage` package - can you tell us what that is? There is a function within `PIL` to resize images - have you tried using that?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the files in the current directory

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage

base = '/the/path'
for path in os.listdir(base):
    with Image.open(os.path.join(base, path)) as image:
        cover = resizeimage.resize_cover(image, [200, 100])
        cover.save(path, image.format)
```

Comment: But i'm getting this error
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-7e453d436820> in <module>()
----> 6     with open(path, 'r+b') as f:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '14325.jpg'

Comment: PIL Image expects a string instead of a file, I just did a typo there. Edited!

Comment: i also made that change before, I think there is some other issue
Are you able to execute it in a folder of some images?@Pablo martinez?

Comment: Ops, you need to add the path to the open

Comment: now this error is shown
----> 7     with Image.open(os.join(base, path)) as image:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: Ye, its os.path.join, I typed it quick

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** Now uses `os.listdir()` instead of `glob.glob()` because of the need generate new file names from the original. Code now saves the resized images in same folder with its original file plus an added suffix.

Note that `Image.open()` wants a file path passed to it, not an opened file.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage

img_folder = '/path/to/img_folder'
fileext = '.jpg'
suffix = '_RESIZED'

for img_filename in os.listdir(img_folder):
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(img_filename)

    if ext == fileext:
        print(filename, ext)
        src_img_filepath = os.path.join(img_folder, img_filename)
        dst_img_filepath = os.path.join(img_folder, filename+suffix, ext)

        with Image.open(src_img_filepath) as image:
            cover = resizeimage.resize_cover(image, [200, 100])
            cover.save(dst_img_filepath, image.format)
```

Comment: i don't know why, but it is giving out only one image as output,not all the images present in my folder

Comment: That could happen if there's only one image file with the `.png` extension in the folder. You could try `*.*` to get all the files in the folder.

Comment: I have 30 images and all of them have .jpg extension, even then,I'm getting only one image as output

Comment: The code, which I simply copied from yours, saves all of the resized images to the same output file named `'test-image-cover.jpeg'`. You need to change that—which could be done by adding a prefix or suffix to each one, **or** using the same file name, but save it in a different folder.