# How to resize the images in order to have the same dimension in the end?

Tags: python, algorithm, image, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I need to resize the the images within a folder in Python. By using the code below, how can I have the same dimension of them in the end?

```
from PIL import Image
import os

path = "E:/Jupyter-Project/images/test/car/"
resize_ratio = 0.5 

def resize_aspect_fit():
    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    for item in dirs:
        if item == '.jpg':
            continue
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            image = Image.open(path+item)
            file_path, extension = os.path.splitext(path+item)

            new_image_height = int(image.size[0] / (1/resize_ratio))
            new_image_length = int(image.size[1] / (1/resize_ratio))

            image = image.resize((new_image_height, new_image_length), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image.save(file_path + "_small" + extension, 'JPEG', quality=90)


resize_aspect_fit()
```

The code works perfect, but some images are 3 K, others are 4... and I do not really know how to modify it in order to achieve the same dimension.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same dimension of them"?

Comment: By this I mean that I need all of the images to be *exactly 4 KB*, for example. Instead of how it is working now - some have 3 KB in the end, some 4 KB, some 5 KB and so on ..

Comment: _Which_ dimension of them, width or height? The code you have now just makes both dimension ½ what they were originally.

Comment: both width and height

Comment: They are all square? Regardless, see [resizing all images in a folder using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071683/resizing-all-images-in-a-folder-using-pil)

Comment: *"By this I mean that I need all of the images to be exactly 4 KB"* Sorry, that's not going to happen with JPEG images. If you want images that are all the same file size, you need to use a file format that doesn't use compression. But then all of the files will be much bigger than the corresponding JPEG files.

Comment: @user3386109: The OP is talking about the dimension of image — its width and height in pixels — not file size.

Comment: @martineau How does KB ([see OP's first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65649035/how-to-resize-the-images-in-order-to-have-the-same-dimension-in-the-end?noredirect=1#comment116070491_65649035)) translate to image dimensions?

Comment: @user3386109: It's unclear what the OP meant and is the first thing I asked them (see very first comment). I think it's what I said and is what the "aspect" of an image usually means. The OP could / should clarify what they want so we don't have to guess.