# created and edited image with pillow, gives an error "attribute access"

Tags: python, resize, python-imaging-library

So, I'm trying to create a image fill it up with colors and then display it for debugging.  I've created the image with pillow, set it to black or, (0,0,0) in rgb, I cycle through and fill up the image with actual color, etc.  But then I get an error for some attribute I don't know how to fill up in python.

```py
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
import copy
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import filedialog


colorwheel = Image.new('RGB', (1, 255*7), color='black')
     colorwheel = colorwheel.load()
     colorwheel[0,1]=(255,255,0)
     colorwheel[0,2] = (255, 255, 0)
     r=255
     g=255
     b=0
     #keep value of green, add take away red
     for i in range( 255):
          colorwheel[0, i] = (255-1, 255, 0)


     #go to blue take away green
     for i in range( 255):
          colorwheel[0,255*2 + i] = (0, 255-i,0+1)

     #go to purple 128 keep blue, add red to 128
     for i in range (255):
          colorwheel[0, 255*3 + i] = (int(i/2), 0, 255)

     #go to red
     for i in range( 255):
          colorwheel[0,255*4 + i]=(int(i/2),0,255-i)

     #go to orange
     for i in range(255):
          colorwheel[0, 255 * 5 + i] = (128, int(i / 2), 0) #keep red 128


     for i in range(255):
          colorwheel[0, 255 * 6 + i] =(128,int(128+i/2),0)



     colorwheel.resize((50,255*7))
     cv2.imshow('image', colorwheel)
```

It should have everything it needs to resize and display the image, but I get this.

```
File "C:/Users/misterE/PycharmProjects/frame2cc/base contraster", line 64, in <module>
    colorwheel.resize((50,255*7))
AttributeError: 'PixelAccess' object has no attribute 'resize'
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do? Resize an image? Display the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:-

```
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
import copy
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import filedialog


colorwheel1 = Image.new('RGB', (1, 255*7), color='black')
colorwheel = colorwheel1.load()
colorwheel[0,1]=(255,255,0)
colorwheel[0,2] = (255, 255, 0)
r=255
g=255
b=0
#keep value of green, add take away red
for i in range( 255):
     colorwheel[0, i] = (255-1, 255, 0)

 #go to blue take away green
for i in range( 255):
     colorwheel[0,255*2 + i] = (0, 255-i,0+1)

 #go to purple 128 keep blue, add red to 128
for i in range (255):
     colorwheel[0, 255*3 + i] = (int(i/2), 0, 255)

#go to red
for i in range( 255):
     colorwheel[0,255*4 + i]=(int(i/2),0,255-i)

#go to orange
for i in range(255):
     colorwheel[0, 255 * 5 + i] = (128, int(i / 2), 0) #keep red 128


for i in range(255):
     colorwheel[0, 255 * 6 + i] =(128,int(128+i/2),0)



colorwheel1.resize((50,255*7))
colorwheel1.show()
```

**OUTPUT IMAGE:-**

[image]

The reason for your error was, that you were trying to use `Image` object command (`Image.resize()`) on a `PixelAccess` element. Which caused this error. For fixing that, we just changed the name of the original Image object to `colorwheel1` so that we can further use this object for resizing.

**P.S.:-** I used `Image.show()` in the end for displaying the image rather then `cv2.imshow()`.

Comment: sweet, thx, obviously i botched the wheel, but now i can see where

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `PixelAccess` doesn't have the function `resize()`, according to the [Pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/PixelAccess.html).

If you're looking to resize an image, [this post about resizing an image using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio) might be useful!