# How to display a range of images within a folder in Python Jupyter?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to show a set of images in a folder, suppose the folder has 100 images and I want to show the first 10 in grid order.

and also having the same size 300x300

If the image is larger than 300x300 rescale.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMzJN.png)

I have this code but I don't know how to rescale the image to size 300 * 300

```
from IPython.display import Image
from IPython.display import display
x = Image(filename="/content/workspace/model/SAE_preview_SAE masked.jpg") 
y = Image(filename="/content/workspace/model/SAE_preview_SAE masked.jpg") 
display(x, y)
```

Comment: Show us some code, or tell what did you tried already. We are here to help with some particular problem, not to write whole code for you.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I resize an image using PIL and maintain its aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio)

This would solve the resizing issue. You can ignore aspect ratio if you do not need that.

There after using `glob` module of python could display all the images in the folder.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html