# Is there any way to make PIL's ImageGrab.grab() save photos with a small size?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using PIL with Python 3.8 to make screenshots of my screeen but the size of them is too large. How can I reduce it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resize an image using PIL and maintain its aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Image.resize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) to shrink the image prior to saving.

Answer (score 1):

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("hopper.jpg")
# Provide the target width and height of the image
(width, height) = (im.width // 2, im.height // 2)
im_resized = im.resize((width, height))
```

source [PIL Docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize)