# Upcale/Downscale image captures by pyautogui.screenshot()

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using **pyautogui** to take screenshot of a certain area.

```
img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(width - 75, length - 181, 190, 27))
```

Now I can successfully it into string.

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

But I want to **upscale the image to 400%** before converting to string. Using **cv2** has some compatibility issues maybe because it is a **PIL** image. Is there any alternative to do that with few lines of code?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resize an image using PIL and maintain its aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 3):

Just use PIL/Pillow's `resize()`:

```
from PIL import Image

....
....
img = img.resize((newX, newY))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio