# How do I resize this image by half?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to resize an image by half and show it. Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image

image0 = Image.open("cwu_logo0.jpg")

image0Width = image0.width
image0Height = image0.height

print(image0Width)
print(image0Height)

image0Resized = image0.resize(image0Width/2, image0Height/2)
image0Resized.show()
```

An error occurs when I run this code, I have trouble understanding it:

```
ValueError: Unknown resampling filter (77.0). Use Image.NEAREST (0), Image.LANCZOS (1), Image.BILINEAR (2), Image.BICUBIC (3), Image.BOX (4) or Image.HAMMING (5)
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('/your image path/image.jpg') # image extension *.png,*.jpg
new_width  = 200
new_height = 300
img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('output image name.png')
```

Referenece:- [How do I resize an image using PIL and maintain its aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio)