# How can you maintain the aspect ratio when using the Python Image Library and ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("somefile.py"))

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, scale

I have searched this up on the internet however all of the results included answers where you use `Image.open("somefile.py")`, however, I was unable to find how to maintain the aspect ratio and scale down the image when using `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("somefile.py"))` together with the GUI library, Tkinter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resize an image using PIL and maintain its aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Also `ImageTk` just converts the image so that it can be used by tkinter. It doesn't change its size.

Answer (score 2):

You want the [thumbnail()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail) method:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open the image
im = Image.open('SomeFile.png')

# Create reduced version whilst maintaining aspect ratio
im.thumbnail((newWidth,newHeight))

# Make ImageTk.PhotoImage from resized image
tkPI = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
```